# How to get latest date from a column in a table in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to get the latest date from my OrderItem table using sql, asp.net. However, when i run the program, they show this error:
`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.`

Here are my codes:

```
    string strconnect =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strconnect);

    string command = "
      Select OrderItem.ProductID, Product.Name, OrderItem.TotalQty, Product.UnitPrice, OrderItem.TotalPrice 
      FROM OrderItem 
      INNER JOIN Product ON OrderItem.ProductID=Product.ProductID 
      WHERE OrderDate = MAX(OrderDate) from OrderItem";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, myConnect);

    myConnect.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    GridView1.DataSource = reader;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    reader.Close();
    myConnect.Close();
```

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove "from OrderItem" in your WHERE condition since you have specified in your FROM clause.

```
SELECT
    i.ProductID,
    p.Name,
    i.TotalQty,
    p.UnitPrice,
    i.TotalPrice 
FROM 
    OrderItem i
        INNER JOIN Product p
            ON i.ProductID = p.ProductID 
WHERE
    i.OrderDate = (SELECT MAX(OrderDate) 
                   FROM OrderItem 
                   WHERE OrderItem.ProductID = i.ProductID)
```

Comment: An error then occured: `An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list.`

Comment: Why this is the best answer even the SQL is invalid ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.ProductID, p.Name, o.TotalQty, p.UnitPrice, o.TotalPrice 
FROM OrderItem AS o
INNER JOIN Product AS p ON o.ProductID = p.ProductID
ORDER BY o.OrderDate DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Ahh, you are using SQL-server, try this: (however not tested)

```
SELECT TOP 1 o.ProductID, p.Name, o.TotalQty, p.UnitPrice, o.TotalPrice 
FROM OrderItem AS o
INNER JOIN Product AS p ON o.ProductID = p.ProductID
ORDER BY o.OrderDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is data type of order date. You may need to change the data type of the variable or apply truncation.

```
declare @MaxOrderDate datetime
select @MaxOrderDate = MAX(OrderItem.OrderDate) from OrderItem

Select
    OrderItem.ProductID,
    Product.Name,
    OrderItem.TotalQty,
    Product.UnitPrice,
    OrderItem.TotalPrice 
FROM 
    OrderItem 
        INNER JOIN Product 
            ON OrderItem.ProductID=Product.ProductID 
WHERE
    OrderItem.OrderDate = @MaxOrderDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the subquery in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT OrderItem.ProductID, Product.Name, OrderItem.TotalQty, Product.UnitPrice, OrderItem.TotalPrice 
FROM OrderItem 
INNER JOIN Product ON OrderItem.ProductID=Product.ProductID 
WHERE OrderDate = ( SELECT MAX(OrderDate) FROM OrderItem );
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question. When answering questions, it is best to explain a little about the code and how it solves the problem. BTW if you disagree with my edit, you can roll it back. To roll an edit back, click on the "edited ... ago" above my avatar picture. That takes you to the edit history. In the edit history, you will find the rollback links.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I will improve my answer next time.